# Access folder inside MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
def OverwriteStorage(instance,filename):
    filename = 'product.csv'
    fullname = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename)
    if os.path.exists(fullname):
        os.remove(fullname)
    return filename
```

[static folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4qkq.jpg)

```
def OverwriteStorage(instance,filename):
   filename = 'product.csv'
   fullname = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename)
   if os.path.exists(fullname):
       os.remove(fullname)
   return "product/{filename}".format(filename=filename)
```

[This code adds new file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WI7t.jpg)
1st block of code overrides the existing file but it's not under product folder.
2nd block of code doesn't overrides the existing file, but is under the product folder.

How should I put the file under product folder overriding the existing file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
def OverwriteStorage(instance,filename):
   filename = 'product.csv'
   fullname = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,'product/', filename)
   if os.path.exists(fullname):
    os.remove(fullname)
   return filename
```

This will save your file in product folder,but I'm not sure if it will replace the existing file.